Highcharts X-Axis Formatting issue
Incoming data is as below, also added the highchart render code and also the parse metrics code. Please check the attaced image which shows that x-axis after a few values get's messed up. We have a lot of entries in the axis, is there an efficient way to showcase some of those values ?
: 
Array(4536)
[0 … 99]
0
: 
{time: 1713773497767, ampere_hours_of_battery_discharge_per_day: 0, apparent_power_of_load: 0, A_phase_grid_active_power: 0, A_phase_load_rate: 0, …}
1
: 
{time: 1713773517767, ampere_hours_of_battery_discharge_per_day: 0, apparent_power_of_load: 0, A_phase_grid_active_power: 0, A_phase_load_rate: 0, …}
2
: 
{time: 1713773537768, ampere_hours_of_battery_discharge_per_day: 0, apparent_power_of_load: 0, A_phase_grid_active_power: 0, A_phase_load_rate: 0, …}
3
: 
{time: 1713773547768, ampere_hours_of_battery_discharge_per_day: 0, apparent_power_of_load: 0, A_phase_grid_active_power: null, A_phase_load_rate: 0, …}

and the code which parse the data is below:
function parseDeviceMetrics(deviceMetrics) {
      if (deviceMetrics && typeof deviceMetrics === 'object' && deviceMetrics.status === "SUCCESS") {
        // Prepare categories and series for the chart
        let categories = [];
        let seriesMap = {};

        // Assuming deviceMetrics.data is an array of data points
        deviceMetrics.data.forEach(dataPoint => {
            // Convert timestamp to a Date object
            const date = new Date(dataPoint.time);

            // Determine the category label based on the current frequency
            let categoryLabel;
            switch (currentFrequency) {
                case 'day':
                    // Use hours and minutes for daily data
                    const hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                    const minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                    categoryLabel = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
                    break;
                case 'week':
                case 'month':
                  // Use full date for weekly or monthly data
                  const year = date.getFullYear();
                  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
                  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                  const hoursMonth = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                  const minutesMonth = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                  categoryLabel = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hoursMonth}:${minutesMonth}`;
                  break;
                default:
                    // Default to full time string
                    categoryLabel = date.toLocaleString();
                    break;
            }

            // Add category if it's not already included
            if (!categories.includes(categoryLabel)) {
                categories.push(categoryLabel);
            }

            // Process each metric in the data point
            Object.keys(dataPoint).forEach(metricKey => {
                const value = dataPoint[metricKey];
                if (metricKey !== 'time' && value !== null) {
                    if (!seriesMap[metricKey]) {
                        seriesMap[metricKey] = { name: metricKey, data: [] };
                    }
                    seriesMap[metricKey].data.push(value);
                }
            });
        });

        // Convert seriesMap to array
        let series = Object.values(seriesMap);
        console.log("Hie");
        console.log(series);
        // Sort categories if necessary based on the first category item
        if (categories.length > 0 && new Date(categories[0]).getTime()) {
            categories.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
        }

        // Prepare formatted data for charting
        formattedData = { categories, series };

        return formattedData;
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch device metrics:", deviceMetrics);
      }
}

The HighChart code is as below:

function renderChart() {
  if (!formattedData.series || !Array.isArray(formattedData.series)) {
    console.error('formattedData.series is not an array:', formattedData.series);
    return; // Exit the function early to prevent further errors
  }

  const chartTitleMapping = {
    'energyChart': 'Energy Generated',
    'stateOfCharge': 'State of Charge',
    'packVoltage': 'Pack Voltage',
    'systemTemperature': 'System Temperature',
    'solarChargeState': 'Solar Charge State'
  };

  const seriesKey = mapChartTypeToSeriesKey(currentChartType);

  // Filter series based on the currentChartType
  const series = formattedData.series.filter(s => s.name === seriesKey).map(s => ({
    name: chartTitleMapping[currentChartType],
    data: s.data
  }));
  Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
           useUTC: false
      }
  });

  console.log(formattedData.categories);
  Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
    chart: {
      type: currentGraphType // Dynamically set chart type (line or bar)
    },
    title: {
      text: chartTitleMapping[currentChartType] || 'Dynamic Chart Title'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      categories: formattedData.categories,
      labels: {
              "format": "{value}"
           }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value' // Customize based on chart type
      }
    },
    series: series.length > 0 ? series : [{ name: 'No data', data: [] }] // Handle case where no series data is available
  });
}


What is the issue in x-axis rendering as shown in attached image ?
The render happens as below attached image:


You should use xAxis.type: 'datetime' if you want to present data over years, months, days or hours. Then you should pass the x values in the data as milliseconds.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tpu5rfog/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats
